# The difference between using DataSet and Table on a Master/details relation?

Tags: delphi

Are the results the same? because I tried and I don't see anything that changes except in DataSet, I can write a query/command while on Table I can select the table only.

Comment: Your question is too broad, but Table is table, DataSet may be table, query etc. So the short answer of this question can be  : Yes the result will be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried and I don't see anything that changes except in DataSet, I can write a
>   query/command while on Table I can select the table only.

Your observation is broadly correct because you need to know whether a particular Table type supports being used on the Detail side of a Master-Detail relationship and, if it does, how to configure it.

Delphi has Table-like descendants for various
database types, e.g. TTable for the (obsolete) BDE, TADOTable for ADO, etc.  Whether they support being on the Detail side of a Master-Detail
relationship is up to the author of the particular table type and so is 
what you need to do to get a given Table type to handle Detail dataset behaviour.

Taking Delphi'ssupplied ADO components as an example, if you are using a TADOQuery
as the Detail dataset, you write the SQL for it to include a WHERE clause which links
the dataset to the Master, as in

```
`where masterid = :masterid`
```

adnd set its `DataSource` property to the datasource connected to the Master table.

To use a TADODataSet as the detail, there is the problem that you can only (easily) set
the (detail) table name, not which records from it are retrieved to match the Master row.
The way TADOTable's authors chose to address this is to

- give the `TADOTable` `MasterFields` and `MasterSource` properties which you use to
  link the ADOTable to the Master dataset
- use the `Filter` property of the underlying `RecordSet` object to a filter expression
  which filters out all but the matching Detail records.  See `procedure TCustomADODataSet.ActivateTextFilter` in ADODB.Pas.

Example project:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    qMaster: TADOQuery;
    qDetail: TADOQuery;
    dsMaster: TDataSource;
    tDetail: TADOTable;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qMaster.Connection := AdoConnection1;
  qMaster.SQL.Text := 'select * from master';

  qDetail.Connection := AdoConnection1;
  qDetail.SQL.Text := 'select * from detail where masterid = :masterid';
  qDetail.DataSource := dsMaster;

  // tDetail is a TADOTable
  tDetail.Connection := AdoConnection1;
  tDetail.TableName := 'detail';
  tDetail.MasterSource := dsMaster;
  tDetail.MasterFields := 'MasterID';


  qMaster.Open;
  qDetail.Open;
  tDetail.Open;

end;
```